# Spring Boot - Using Qualifiers with Profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following which uses qualifiers and the profile `dev`.  When `!dev` `Service1` will use `FooImpl1` based on the qualifier and `Service2` will use `FooImpl2`.  When the the profile is `dev` I want both services to use `FooImpl3`.  How can I accomplish that?

```
interface Foo {
  public void fooToYou();
}

@Component("fooImpl1")
@Profile("!dev")
public class FooImpl1 implements Foo {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

@Component("fooImpl2")
@Profile("!dev")
public class FooImpl2 implements Foo {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

@Component("fooImpl3")
@Profile("dev")
public class FooImpl3 implements Foo {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

public class Service1 {
  @Autowired
  public void Service1(@Qualifier("fooImpl1") Foo foo) {}
}

public class Service2 {
  @Autowired
  public void Service1(@Qualifier("fooImpl2") Foo foo) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do what I was ultimately attempting to accomplish by removing the qualifiers and using inheritance.

```
interface BaseFoo {
  public void fooToYou();
}

interface Foo1 extends BaseFoo {}
interface Foo2 extends BaseFoo {}

@Profile("!dev")
class FooImpl1 implements Foo1 {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

@Profile("!dev")
class FooImpl2 implements Foo2 {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

class BaseDevFooImpl implements BaseFoo {
  @Override
  public void fooToYou() {}
}

@Profile("dev")
class DevFooImpl1 extends BaseDevFooImpl implements Foo1 {}

@Profile("dev")
class DevFooImpl2 extends BaseDevFooImpl implements Foo2 {}

class Service1 {
  @Autowired
  public void Service1(Foo1 foo) {}
}

class Service2 {
  @Autowired
  public void Service1(Foo2 foo) {}
}
```